# Transaction size and latency between: CPU and RAM, RAM and PCIE2.0 16x device

Tags: cpu, ram, latency, pci-e

What is the minimum transaction size in bytes, and what with the latency in clock cycles or nanoseconds?
For:

1. access the CPU(Sandy/Ivy Bridge) to RAM
2. DMA access between the RAM and the device by PCIE 2.0 16x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question (partly)

**2:** A few (chip to chip) figures are in the paper [here](http://www.hypertransport.org/docs/wp/Low_Latency_Final.pdf) (at the end, Table 1 and 2)

Note also that the latency depends also on how big the PCIE packets are.

To complicate it there is also some latency introduced by the OS and the Graphiccards driver (reading/writing memory, User-Kernel land switching time, and so on).

Comment: Good article. So, for the block size of 1 - 8 bytes delay is **250ns**. For blocks in 2K delay is 1000ns, and as I understand precisely the delay doesn't affected to this value, and the bandwidth affect to it (2GB/sec for PCI-E 1.0 8x, since Article 2006).
And coding 8b/10b, explains the fall bandwidth with the stated specification 8GB/sec for PCI-E 2.0 16x, to the real characteristics of bandwidth a 6 GB/sec on my ​​tests.

Comment: And if I understand correctly from the following pictures, the delay for caches: L1 - 1ns, L2 - 3ns, L3 - 10ns, RAM - **50ns**. And for CPU 3GHz in ticks: L1 - 3ticks, L2 - 10ticks, L3 - 30ticks, RAM - 150ticks. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ldCnq.gif

Answer (score 0):

Minimum transfer size is 0 which does not have any effect at both sides. With data, minimum transfer size is 1 doubleword(4 bytes)

Comment: Is it true both for RAM and for PCI-E?